# Jquery Mobile table example

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've seen the demos on jquery mobile website and found this table example - http://jquerymobile.com/branches/tables/docs/tables/movie-list.html.

But when I try to use this on Mobile the table does not fit in the screen. The reflow table does not work.

Can anyone point me to any work example of a Jquery Mobile table please?

Thanks.